# Elasticsearch reindex error - client request timeout

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to reindex using following line:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "poi_201705"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "poi_dev_2"
  }
}
```

But I am getting following error in kibana console:

```
{
  "statusCode": 504,
  "error": "Gateway Time-out",
  "message": "Client request timeout"
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is this issue and how can get rid of it.

Comment: Possibly it can't connect to that instance of ES. try curl for the src ES url once

Comment: @VirajParab How to curl

Comment: try 'curl <src_url>:<port>' eg: curl http://poi_201705:9200 . and check if you get the response from the computer where you are running the reindex

Answer (score 56, accepted):

504 simply means that the request is still running but the HTTP connection from Kibana to ES timed out.

You can still see the request going on by using the task management API like this:

```
GET _tasks?actions=*reindex&detailed
```

If you want to run the task asynchronously you can also do it with the following command:

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
```

This will return a task id whose progress can then be checked with:

```
GET _tasks/<task-id>
```

Comment: yes the request is still running. But I check using _cat?indices. my source store.size of poi_201705 832.7mb but store.size of poi_dev_2 is 824.2mb while docs.count remain same

Comment: which is normal right? since you reindex the source index into the destination index, the document count will be the same in both indices (provided that the destination index was initially empty). Don't worry about the store size, that's not a relevant figure, only the doc count matters

Comment: will have questions soon. I am just a newbie in elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please update with `POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false` in order to run task async at the first place?

Comment: @Anton good idea, done!

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but on a _search query. Using the GET _tasks returns only a json with a key: `nodes` and nothing more. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu please create a question for your issue

Answer (score 0):

- To see your indices you can check `GET _cat/indices/source_index,destination_index` API call result in Kibana Dev Tools.
- To compare the number of documents with `GET source_index,destination_index/_count` API.

**To prevent** `504 Gateway Time-out Client request timeout` error, you can use `?wait_for_completion=false`.

> If the request contains wait_for_completion=false, Elasticsearch
> performs some preflight checks, launches the request, and returns a
> task you can use to cancel or get the status of the task.
> Elasticsearch creates a record of this task as a document at
> _tasks/<task_id>.
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-task-api

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "conflicts": "proceed",
  "source": {
    "index": "kong-01"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "kong-01-new"
  }
}
```

response:

```
{
  "task": "Djf3dFpkQle-dqjG0sf6tw:45922151"
}
```

check reindex process:

```
GET _tasks/Djf3dFpkQle-dqjG0sf6tw:45922151
```

Example output of tasks API call:

```
{
  "completed": true,
  "task": {
    "node": "Djf3dFpkQle-dqjG0sf6tw",
    "id": 45932237,
    "type": "transport",
    "action": "indices:data/write/reindex",
    "status": {
      "total": 156,
      "updated": 48,
      "created": 92,
      "deleted": 0,
      "batches": 1,
      "version_conflicts": 0,
      "noops": 0,
      "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
      },
      "throttled_millis": 0,
      "requests_per_second": -1,
      "throttled_until_millis": 0
    },
    "description": "reindex from [kong-01] to [kong-01-new]",
    "start_time_in_millis": 1706771247512,
    "running_time_in_nanos": 4811870265,
    "cancellable": true,
    "cancelled": false,
    "headers": {
      "trace.id": "abb652b45138f6becbc163bb918df48d"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "took": 4794,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 156,
    "updated": 48,
    "created": 92,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 1,
    "version_conflicts": 0,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
      "bulk": 0,
      "search": 0
    },
    "throttled": "0s",
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1,
    "throttled_until": "0s",
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": [ ]
    }
}
```