# Why is my elasticsearch update_by_query timing out?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the Javascript library and and trying to perform a rather large update on documents. I have changed the timeout value on the query itself as well as the client object and am still getting a timeout that seems to be 2 minutes. Below is the query.

```
const arrayOfStrings = [...]; // This array could be between 10-12k elements in size
await elasticClient.updateByQuery({
        index: "main-index",
        refresh: true,
        conflicts:"proceed",
        script: {
            lang: "painless",
            source: "ctx._source.status = \"1\"; ctx._source.entities = [];  for(term in params.array) ctx._source.entities.add(term);",
            params: {
                "array": arrayOfStrings
            }
        },
        query: { 
            "term": {
                "parent_id": 'dgd39gd3-db3dg23879-d893gdg38-e23ed' // There could be upwards of 5000 documents that match this criteria
            }
        },
        timeout: "5m"
});
```

Also on the elastic client, I have `requestTimeout` set to '5m' as well. I can understand why this particular query may be timing out as its applying a 12k element array to a field on 5k documents. However I dont understand why the query is timing out after only 2 minutes when I have timeout values set that are longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do here is to run the [update by query asynchronously](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-task-api)

```
await elasticClient.updateByQuery({
    index: "main-index",
    refresh: true,
    conflicts:"proceed",
    waitForCompletion: false              <---- add this setting
```

And then you can [follow the progress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51853003/4604579) of the task running asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you! Im going to accept this as the answer, however I am interested as to why the timeout values wernt having an effect. This could be useful to people who come across this scenario.

Comment: Also the setting is actually wait_for_completion as of 2022.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped! Both `waitForCompletion` and `wait_for_completion` used to be correct, but indeed the latter is preferred. Regarding the timeout, it's not working as you expect because it works at the query/shard level, not for the full update by query command, which means your actual query never takes 5 minutes, the timeout you're getting is because the update takes longer than what the HTTP client is ready to wait for in order to get a synchronous response.